# Array values gone wrong

Tags: c

I'm having some problems with my code.

My program calculates the amount of resistance based on the color of the three bands coming from an input file, then printing out to an output file.

Example input file:

```
red, green, blue   
green, gray, yellow
```

Example output file:

```
Resistance in ohms = 680  
Resistance in kilo-ohms = 1420
```

However, every time I run the program it crashes. I've done some debugging and found that it has a problem with the `yellow` index from `decodeString` function giving it a `NULL` value. I've partially fixed that problem by passing the values to the function `decodeString` instead of using pointers and now it seems to work.

Right now I don't get the correct output that I'm expecting and I don't know where the error is coming from. The code I have runs, but doesn't give the correct output at the moment. I just don't know where to look anymore.

Think anyone can help me fix this? Or if there's anything that I might have done wrong please point it out and explain why it went wrong. That'll be greatly appreciated!

The commented lines were used for debugging.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define size 100

int DecodeString(char inputString[]){
  const char kColorTable[10][10] = {"black", "brown", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "violet", "gray", "white"};
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf("\n>>%s,%s", inputString, kColorTable[i]);
    if(strcmp(inputString, kColorTable[i]) == 0){
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

int main(){
  int i=0, colord[3]={0,0,0};
  char color[size], *token, *inputString;
  double resistance=0, value;

  FILE *fptrin, *fptrout;
  if(((fptrin = fopen("input.txt", "r"))==NULL) || ((fptrout = fopen("output.txt", "w")) == NULL)){
    printf("Error 404: File not found");
    exit(1);
  }

  while(fgets(color, size, fptrin) != NULL) {
    i = 0;
    token = strtok(color, ", \n");
    while(token != NULL && i < 3) {
        colord[i] = DecodeString(token);
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, ", \n");
    }

    if (colord[0] == -1 || colord[1] == -1 || colord[2] == -1){
      printf("\n\nBad code -- cannot compute resistance\n");
    }

    else{
      resistance = (10.0 * colord[0] + colord[1]) * pow(10.0, colord[2]);
    }

    printf("%f",resistance);
    if(resistance > 1000){
      fprintf(fptrout,"Resistance in Kilo-Ohms: %f",resistance/1000);
    }

    else{
      fprintf(fptrout,"Resistance in Ohms: %f",resistance);
    }
  }

  //fclose(fptrin);
  //fclose(fptrout);

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to debug my program to find out what's going on and this is the result that I get. Which I suppose is why I can't get the output right.

> > > blue,black
> > >       blue,brown
> > >       blue,red
> > >       blue,orange
> > >       blue,yellow
> > >       blue,green
> > >       blue,blue
> > >       red,black
> > >       red,brown
> > >       red,red
> > >       ,blackn
> > >       ,brownn
> > >       ,redown
> > >       ,orange
> > >       ,yellow
> > >       ,greenn
> > >       ,bluewn
> > >       ,violet
> > >       ,graywn
> > >       ,whiten

I didn't realize it was the old code I had copied in. The results remain the same.

Comment: Why don't you put newline into your `strtok()` delimiter string, so you won't have to check for it specially. `strtok(color, ",\n")`

Comment: For some reason your `strtok()` loop is finding an empty token instead of the third color.

Comment: Is there really a space after the commas in the input file? Because your code doesn't remove that. I wonder how it's ever matching the second and third color. Try using `strtok("color, ", \n")` so it skips the spaces as well.

Comment: Or instead of using `strtok()`, you could use `sscanf()` with the format string `" %[^,], %[^,], %s"`

Comment: Seems to be a repeat of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102475/passing-of-values-from-text-file-to-array) but OP has not even bothered to correct the wrong output of his example, or take any advice. So why the deluge of up-votes?

Comment: Why 5 upvote? His question is about debug his program...

Comment: @WeatherVane people on this side of the Earth must like resistor related questions more.

Comment: I already added i = 0 and it still doesn't work. I'll update this.

Comment: @S.Pinkus then they should **resist** the OP's previous assertion that "black,gray,green" is 800K, when it should be "gray,black,yellow".

Comment: @JeffersonPonce of course it does not work. You are still not filtering out the spaces in the text file, as you were previously advised in both answers. Do get up to speed.

Comment: I didn't realize it was my older code that I had copied in. I've edited them now.